# Почему не меняется цвет бекграунда в EditText

Tags: java, android

Хочу поменять цвет бэкграунда в EditText с белого на серый, использую такой код для этого:

```
 <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etMessage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rectangle_edit_text"
                android:hint="@string/conversation_activity_hint"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@color/colorMain"
                emojicon:emojiconSize="32sp" />
```

И код `drawable`, который используется для `background` `rectangle_edit_text.xml`:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorGrey" />
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:topRightRadius="15dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Вероятно, вы брали код <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646415/how-to-create-edittext-with-rounded-corners"> отсюда </a>? Посмотрите, ответ обновили :)

Comment: нет, не от туда, но очень похоже. Мне нужно что бы background в EditText всегда был серым, так а что неправильно?

Answer (score 1):

Вынесите `padding` из параметров `Shape`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<padding android:bottom="10dp"
    android:top="10dp"
    android:left="10dp"
    android:right="10dp"/> 

<solid
    android:color="@color/colorGrey" >
</solid>

<corners
    android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
    android:topRightRadius="15dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Вынесла padding, а потом вообще его убрала для теста, но цвет бекграунда для EditText, все равно остался белым.

Comment: может у вас colorGray - белый?)

Comment: Нет, не белый, даже черный цвет поставила для теста, в Preview показывает, что бекграунд меняет цвет, но на телефоне белый, тестировала на нескольких телефонах.